# PHP associative array null in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, associative-array

I have a PHP webpage containing 6 textboxes as given below:

```
<html>
   <script type="text/javascript">

        function add()
        {
            //PHP associative array not storing properly in JS array

            var array = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($elementsindex); ?>);//getting array

            //JS array elements not printing
            for(var i in array)
            {
                alert("key = "+i+" and value = "+array[i]);
            }

            for(var key in array)
            {
                if(array[key]===null || array[key]===0)//for loop not executing
                {
                    var valtoadd = 5;

                    array[key] = valtoadd;//add value to index IN ARRAY

                    var textbox = document.getElementById(key);
                    textbox.value = valtoadd;//add value to textbox 
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
   <body>
   <form method="POST" action="">
      <div id="operation">
            <input type="text" id = "5E" name="5E" value="">
            <input type="text" id = "4E" name="4E" value="" >
            <input type="text" id = "3E" name="3E" value="">
            <input type="text" id = "2E" name="2E" value="">
            <input type="text" id = "1E" name="1E" value="">
            <input type="text" id = "0E" name="0E" value="">
        </div>
        ....rest of the code
     </form>
        ..php code
```

I have a PHP code in the same page that invokes the Javascript function add() on a particular buttonclick() which is working perfectly:

```
   <?php
    include 'footer.php';

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['PUSH']))
    { 
        //I am creating an associative array
        $elementsindex = array("0E"=>0 ,"1E"=>0,"2E"=>0, "3E"=>0, "4E"=>0, "5E"=>0);

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'add();'; //invoking JS function
        echo '</script>';
    }
    ?>
```

However in the Javascript function add(), the PHP array is not getting stored in var array. Also, the array elements are not printing in the alert box and the code never executes the for(var key in array) loop.

I am sure that the associative array is being passed correctly (the Javascript function is invoked successfully), but maybe not being received at the JS function because initially all the values in the key-value pair are zero (required for the project).

Comment: `"2E"=>$0, "3E"=>$val3E`. can you explain this? I think in 2E, you mean 0 instead of $0.

Comment: yes @david i meant 0.

Comment: PHP has associative arrays. JavaScript doesn't. If the keys are not numeric, then JSON.parse will return you a JavaScript object instead.

Answer (score 0):

This code stores the `$a` into an object variable. I simply change the way to obtain the value.

```
var obj = <?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;
for (var i in obj)
{
    alert("key = " + i + " and value = " + obj[i]);
}
```

Comment: weird. you use my code, right? I tested mine and it works.

Comment: yes i have used your code; do the php array elements get printed in your code i.e key = 0E and value = 0 and so on..?

Comment: yes, it works as expected. ah, can you post the html form? I don't see any form tag in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176845/discussion-between-david-and-simran).